# Fastest method for string comparison in python

Tags: python, performance, nlp, similarity

I was wondering what's the fastest method to compare similarity between two lists of strings (e.g. two dataframes, documents etc.) using levenshtein distance or other procedures.

I am currently using:

```
def wuzzyfuzzy(df1, df2):
    myList = []
    total = len(df1)
    for idx1, df1_str in enumerate(df1.col1):
        myDict = {}
        my_str = ('Progress : ' + str(round((idx1/total)*100,3))+'%')
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(my_str))
        sys.stdout.flush()

        for idx2, df2_str in enumerate(df2.col1):
            s = SequenceMatcher(None, df1_str, df2_str)
            r = s.ratio()
            myDict.update({df2_str:r})
        best_match = max(myDict, key=myDict.get)
        myList.append([df1_str, best_match, myDict[best_match]])

    return myList
```

As the `dataframes` that are passed to the function have both > 30.000 values, it takes currently around **6 hours** to compare each value in df1 with all other values in df2 to find the best match.

Of course I cleaned the strings as good as possible beforehand (all lowercase, get rid of punctuations etc.)

What's the most efficient way to perfom such task?

Comment: If you have working code and are looking for improvements, you could/should post your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: check this [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157797/efficiently-writing-string-comparison-functions-in-python)

Comment: The shared link reviews a very specific problem and underlying code, where suggestions concerning performance are not really adaptable to my thread. I wanted to raise this question for a broader user base.